# write a Python game that tests the arithmetic skills of the player

Tags: python

Everyone, please help me to address this.
I have no idea how to write code for TOTAL TIME and SCORE.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j95P.png)

I have done most of the code.
Only CALCULATE SCORE, I have no idea how to write code.

Many thanks!

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post what you have done and what problems you are having and we will try to help you.

Comment: HERE my code: https://anotepad.com/note/read/yrhe5h

Comment: I don't know how to write code for calculate the scores.

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to include your code in the form of a [mcve], including the output you want and the output you're getting instead.  Off-site links to code --- and especially off-site links to _images_ of code, inputs, and outputs --- make your question hard to answer now, and useless to other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`yourAnswer` is only set to the answer of the last question, so at most there will be 100 points. You should instead define `answer1`, `answer2`, etc. to store the user's answers and then check those specific answers against the actual answer to the respective questions.